# Function changing parent class not working as expected

Tags: javascript

What I need is to change the class for the parent of an element. I want to use this element's id as a string, so I can use this string now as a class (probably I can skip the string part) Xo)

The element itself is also changed by an external event.

I have this:

```js
function show(id) {
 var vBoxy = document.getElementById(id);
 vBoxy.className = "BoxyAfter";

 parentBox = vBoxy.parentNode;
 parentBox.className = vBoxy;
}
```

```css
.BoxBefore {
  padding: 20px; 
  background-color: #777;}

.Boxy {
  padding: 20px; 
  background-color: #FF0;}

.BoxyBefore {height: 100px; width: 100px;
  background-color: #DDD;}

.BoxyAfter {height: 100px; width: 100px;
  background-color: #F00;}
```

```html
<p onMouseOver="show('Boxy');">Hover me</p>

<div class="BoxBefore">
  <div id="Boxy" class="BoxyBefore">  
  </div>  
</div>
```

The idea is that I can change the style of the background to yellow.

What I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just lost `.id`

```js
function show(id) {
 var vBoxy = document.getElementById(id);
 vBoxy.className = "BoxyAfter";

 parentBox = vBoxy.parentNode;
 parentBox.className = vBoxy.id;
}
```

```css
.BoxBefore {
  padding: 20px; 
  background-color: #777;}

.Boxy {
  padding: 20px; 
  background-color: #FF0;}

.BoxyBefore {height: 100px; width: 100px;
  background-color: #DDD;}

.BoxyAfter {height: 100px; width: 100px;
  background-color: #F00;}
```

```html
<p onMouseOver="show('Boxy');">Hover me</p>

<div class="BoxBefore">
  <div id="Boxy" class="BoxyBefore">  
  </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: not sure why this is accepted when I had the same answer 5 minutes earlier. Though changed it later to use "id" rather than "vBody.id".

Answer (score 2):

Should be:

```
parentBox.className = vBoxy.id;
```

The `id` property is a string.

Answer (score 1):

`parentBox.className = vBoxy;` should be `parentBox.className = vBoxy.id;` if you want it to get "Boxy" class, as that's how you get id of vBoxy. 
Or maybe even better solution is `parentBox.className = id`.

```js
function show(id) {
 var vBoxy = document.getElementById(id);
 vBoxy.className = "BoxyAfter";

 parentBox = vBoxy.parentNode;
 parentBox.className = id;
}
```

```css
.BoxBefore {
  padding: 20px; 
  background-color: #777;}

.Boxy {
  padding: 20px; 
  background-color: #FF0;}

.BoxyBefore {height: 100px; width: 100px;
  background-color: #DDD;}

.BoxyAfter {height: 100px; width: 100px;
  background-color: #F00;}
```

```html
<p onMouseOver="show('Boxy');">Hover me</p>

<div class="BoxBefore">
  <div id="Boxy" class="BoxyBefore">  
  </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: I have a question on why "parentBox.className = id;" uses the id from vBoxy if it is not declared. Should not be taking the id (if exist) of the parent?

Comment: Not sure that I know what do you mean? You send "id" to your method show. And then fetch vBoxy as document.getElementById(id); Logically this means that vBoxy.id === id if vBoxy exists. But vBoxy does exist, or it wouldn't even get to this code because vBoxy.className would already throw error.